# Laravel VUEJS dynamic row with unique value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a function which adds a new row when a button is pressed, however when I have 2 or more rows and get the age of the selected student in the dropdown menu whatever is the value of the last row will also be the value of the first row. How do I fix this?
Here is the select option:

```html
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(form, index) in addForms">
    <td class="text-xs-left">
      <select @change="getAge" v-model="form.student_id" class="form-control">
        <option disabled>Select Student</option>
        <option  v-for="student in students" :value="student.student_id">{{student.student_name}}</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-xs-left">
      <select v-model="form.student_age" class="form-control">
        <option v-for="student in studentAge" :value="student.age">{{student.age}}</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and this is the method to add new row

```js
addForm(){
  this.addForms.push({
    student_id: '',
    student_age: ''
  });
}
```

and for the method to get the age of the student:

```js
getPrice(e){
  axios.get('/api/student',{
    params: {
      student_id: this.addForms[this.addForms.length-1].product_id
    }
  }).then(function(response){
    this.studentAge = response.data;           
  }).bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what does your data look like? I see three v-for loops on addForms, students, and studentAge. It's not apparent how these relate. `<option v-for="student in studentAge"` particularly doesn't make sense to me. Also, I don't think it makes sense to have a v-model inside a v-for. I could be wrong. To me though a v-model is for one piece of data. If you're doing it inside a for loop then you're v-modeling a bunch of values to a specific value, OR you'd need to be doing something like `v-model="someArray[index]"` but that seems hard to read and reason about. [Here's](https://codepen.io/lhovee/pen/wvvOKPE?editors=1010) my attempt at recreating your example in a codepen. If you update it with your data models and explain how things should work maybe that would help?